# /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds permission denied

Tags: permissions

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, and I'm learning out of curiosity about it.

The book I'm reading was talking about `journactl` command, and I decided to check the listing for a particular boot.
To my surprise, I discovered this warning:

```
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
```

In th site, they advised to check the relevant sysfys file:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds
```

I've tried with my user, and it outputted `permission denied`, then I ran `sudo -i`, inserted the password, the thing $ transformed into #. So, right now, I assume I have root privileges. However, when I run `# /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds`, I get `permission denied`

If I run ls on that file, I get:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 abr 10 21:46 /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds
```

So, supposedly, any user should be able to read it...

Comment: "check" in this context means *read* - you appear to be trying to *execute* the file. Try `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/mds`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks ;)